# working with object with spring and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

hope everybody is cool.I've been trying to do something with spring-hibernate but it's still a failure.i'm very new to it.i need a little help.supposing a POJO class Users.i want to return an Users object by username.While i had no problem to return Users object by id by doing this

```
   return (Users) getHibernateTemplate().get(Users.class, id);
```

it seems to be a challenge for me getting the Users object by username. I've tried this

```
List<Users> users = getHibernateTemplate().find("from Users u where u.username=?",username);
return  users.get(0);
```

and even this

```
return (Users)getHibernateTemplate().find("from Users u where u.username=?",username).get(0);
```

how should i do it.And what is the proper way to return an array of Users objects and/or List.Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try this?

```
List l =getHibernateTemplate().find("from Users u where u.username=?",new Object[]{username});
if (l.size() > 0)
 return (User)l.get(0);
else
return null;
```

Comment: Please not the dreaded 'return null' - that's asking for a NullPointerException somewhere shortly after the method containing the above code is called.  My prefered way to deal with this situation would be to throw a UserNotFoundException.

Comment: I don't think you can generalise like that without knowing the context of the operation. Returning a null may be defined by interface contract for all we know.

Comment: i returned a new users object.thanks dudes.What about arrays of Users? supposing i want to return all the users of the name francis?

Comment: And how about all the users name 'james' :). Of course return the list, instead of the first item. Where is the problem? By the way, I am not in the favor of writing SQL for trivial cases while using Hibernate kind of powerful API.

Comment: Ah and in case no user found return an empty list :), instead of throwing exception or returning null. A nice idea indeed, depends on the interface contract though. Cheers.

Comment: yeah :) but i need to start from somewhere before i get to that complexity.i wasn't developing in java before but C#  and was using code author.I learn much better when i try things myself.thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select * from Users u where u.username=:username");
q.setString("username", username);
```

Comment: This is also my preferred way of handling this.  I've found that naming my parameters makes it easier to understand what the code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Another better way is to use Criteria. See the example below.

```
    DetachedCriteria deCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(User.class, "u");
    Criteria criteria = deCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(session);

    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("u.username", username));
    List<User> userList = criteria.list();
```

Comment: i'll try this but i think i'll try it with the spring function findbycriteria and see how it will go along.thanks

Comment: You must, its not encouraged to write SQL for trivial cases while using Hibernate/Spring kind of powerful APIs.